# Matching a string with a known prefix and suffix with regex using Grep

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to match all strings with a known prefix and a mostly known suffix.

The prefix will be any 3 uppercase characters.

The suffix will be one uppercase `C` and zero or one numbers afterward.
ex. `C` or `Cx` where `x` is any number

The middle substring is of unknown length and is uppercase letters only.

#### Examples:

```
GORABJKAC3 [match]
GORCCCCC [match]
GORBBBBCCC [match
GORBBBBCA [no match]
BORBBBBCA2 [no match]
```

I tried something like `grep ^GOR[:upper:]*C[:digit:]*` but that doesn't work.

I think `[:upper:]` may just consume all uppercase letters, including the suffix `C` I want to match.

How can I match my desired string with regex using grep?

Comment: The correct way to use POSIX character class is `[[:upper:]]`

Comment: nhatdh is right, the `regex(7)` man page says: "*Within  a bracket expression*, the name of a character class enclosed in "[:" and ":]" ..." -- you want `^GOR[[:upper:]]*C[[:digit:]]*\>` where the `\>` is an "end-of-word" marker to avoid matching "GORBBBCA" -- or skip the `\>` and use `grep -o`

Comment: If there are potentially other characters in the string after the end-of-word marker, will the marker stop it from trying to match more characters?

Comment: I'd add more to the example to clarify, but apparently code formatted as code isn't formatted as code, and isn't allowed to be posted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
\b[A-Z]{3}.*?C[0-9]?\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nU5jZ2/1)

Or using anchor (if these strings are on separate lines):

```
^[A-Z]{3}.*?C[0-9]?$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[A-Z]` instead of `[:upper:]` and `[0-9]` instead of `[:digit:]`.

Also, `*` means 0 or more, `+` means 1 or more, and `?` means 0 or 1. I think you want to be using `+` and `?`.

`+` and `?` are special Perl regex characters so add the `-P` flag to your grep command.

So final regex : `grep -P ^GOR[A-Z]+C[0-9]?`

Comment: I tried your final regex and it did not work. I even tried `grep ^GOR[A-Z]+C[0-9]?` on a file containing lines with only the example strings, and I got nothing back.

Comment: Oh, you need to use Perl regex and it should have been [A-Z], I'll edit

Comment: I don't think my version of regex has -P. I checked the man pages, and both -P and -o are missing.

Comment: Ok then, `[A-Z]+` can be replaced with `[A-Z][A-Z]*`. and `[0-9]?` can be replaced with `[0-9]{0,1}`